# Разные длины одинаковых строк в C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

```cs
public MainWindow(string filename)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if(filename != null && File.Exists(filename))
    {
        FilePath = filename;
        FileText.Text = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
        DefaultFileText = FileText.Text;
        MessageBox.Show((DefaultFileText.Length == FileText.TextLength).ToString()); // output: false
    }
}
```

Не всегда, но бывает такое, что длины не совпадают, хотя одна строка равна другой. Как исправить?

Comment: а на концах строк нет каких-нибудь невидимых символов типо пробелов или переносов строк?

Comment: А каков хоть тип переменных DefaultFileText и FileText?

Comment: Думаю, в каком-то из элементов либо размер строки ограничен, либо какие-то преобразования строки происходят. Проще всего прямо напечатать что там и что там, да сравнить глазами.

Comment: DefaultFileText - строка, FileText - RichTextBox WinForms, свойством TextLength я получаю длину текста в нем

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Исходный код: [TextLength](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs,2b643614a689880c).

Там комментарий:

> Note: Currently Microsoft does not fully support surrogates - VSW#327396. If   the text contains surrogate characters this property may return incorrect values.

Очевидно, в вашем тексте содержатся суррогатные символы.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался с суррогатными символами, в своем блокноте переписал сохранение файла,указав кодировку при сохранении UTF-8. Сохранил проблемный файл с помощью вышеуказанной кодировки. Пример:  `File.WriteAllText(FilePath, FileText.Text, Encoding.UTF8);`